# Creating a dynamic shell from loading a file

Tags: java, file, shell, dynamic

Let's say a class AnotherShell

```
public class AnotherShell
{
    private Shell shell;
    public AnotherShell()
    {
        shell = new Shell(Display.getCurrent());

        Button btnNewButton = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
        btnNewButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseUp(SelectionEvent e) {
                System.out.print("Selected\n");
            }
        });
    }
    public void open()
    {
        shell.open();
    }

    public void close()
    {
        shell.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

I wonder if it is possible to save this into a file and than from a program that doesn't have this code load the file and "recreate" the windows exactly as if it was part of the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort answer: no (other than saving&loading a screenshot).

Long answer: make `AnotherShell` serializable and store it in a file with another file containing the source code. Have the other program [dynamically load](http://www.javablogging.com/dynamic-in-memory-compilation/) the code and de-serialize the `AnotherShell` window and open it. YMMV.